# ASP.Net MVC DropList value binding to wrong property

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, model-view-controller

I have a model that has two properties, a string setID and a list of strings woID. A set is a collections of workOrders. I'm struggling to get the selected value of the dropdown to bind to woId, when i check in the console only setID is dislayed

```
$("#SetDDL :selected").val();
"TC2010-TEST-2017-OS"
$("#SetDDL :selected").text();
"TC2010-TEST-2017-OS"
```

My model looks like

```
public class SetWoDropDownModel
{
    public string setId { get; set; }
    public List<string> woId { get; set; }
}
```

and this is the dropdown portion of the view

```
@model IEnumerable<Tiamat.WebUI.Areas.ParksRMSetAutomation.Models.SetWoDropDownModel>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Parks Routine Maintenance Sets Automation";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

```
@Html.DropDownList("SetId",
    new SelectList(Model.Select(i => i.setId).Distinct().ToList(), Model.Select(i => i.woId).Distinct().ToList()),"Select Set ID",
    new {@class = "input-large form-control", @id = "SetDDL", @onchange = "setDropDownChange(this.value)"}
    )
```

all that the setDropDownChange is doing is toggling the visibility of a button

```
function setDropDownChange(val) {
if (val !== "") {
$('#btnSubmit').attr('style', 'visibility: visible');
} else {
$('#btnSubmit').attr('style', 'visibility: hidden');
}
```

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I see you're using Distinct() for populating drop down list of texts and values. Are you sure both lists have the same number of items?

Comment: no,  one setId can have any number of woId's attached to it,
e.g 

    "TC2010-TEST-2017-OS"  - "wo-17-123,wo-17-124"
    "TC2011-TEST-2017-OS"  - "wo-17-125,wo-17-126,wo-17-127"
 
will that make a difference?

Comment: First problem is the Razor helper you're using is expecting a list of texts and values to match up each text. One text --> one value. Second, I suspect syntax is incorrect and for that reason value is not being bound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your model has a list of woId items per each setId.

```
var Model = new[]
{
    new { setId = "TC2010-TEST-2017-OS", woId = new[] { "W01", "W05", "W07"}},
    new { setId = "TC2011-TEST-2017-OS", woId = new[] { "W02", "W10" }}        
};
```

Then you can group the items like this.

```
var itemList = from item in Model
    group item.woId by item.setId into g
    select new { setId = g.Key, woId = string.Join(",", g.SelectMany(v=>v).ToArray())};
```

And pass the list to the helper.

```
@Html.DropDownList("SetId",
    new SelectList(itemList, "woId", "setId", null), "Select Set ID",
    new {@class = "input-large form-control", id = "SetDDL",
         onchange = "setDropDownChange(this.value)"
})
```

Resulting HTML looks like this.

```
<select class="input-large form-control" id="SetDDL" name="SetId"
    onchange="setDropDownChange(this.value)">
    <option value="">Select Set ID</option>
    <option value="W01,W05,W07">TC2010-TEST-2017-OS</option>
    <option value="W02,W10">TC2011-TEST-2017-OS</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting closer
 Html.DropDownList("SetId",
        new SelectList(Model, "woId", "setId", Model.Select(i => i.woId).Distinct().ToList()), "Select Set ID",
        new {class = "input-large form-control", id = "SetDDL", onchange = "setDropDownChange(this.value)" }
        )
 
I just need to enumerate the value
"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]"

Comment: *Model.Select(i => i.woId).Distinct().ToList()*, this should be selected value or null.

Comment: i tried leaving it blank but i was getting the same result.

Comment: because it's expecting a string with the value

Comment: In order to get a string with the value try SelectMany(). I have updated my solution.

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much, that last step was taking me down so many wrong paths, that last suggestion worked!